# Is MS Windows known to be non-compliant to RFC3927 or did we hit a bug?

Tags: windows, local-area-network, link-local

We have recently encountered a situation where a Windows 10 machine assigned itself a Local-Link address of 169.254.0.33.

According to our reading of [RFC 3927, section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-2.1), this is not allowed. Ranges 169.254.0.xx, and 169.254.255.xx are reserved for future use and not to be used in auto-assignment.

Interestingly, reading the introduction on section 2 of the same RFC, it claims that, at least at the time of writing, MS Windows "is compatible with the rules in this section".

Is this non-compliance known ? Or have we hit a bug in Windows 10 ? Or are we mis-interpreting something ?

(Additionally, we timidly tried to see if we could get it to assign a different address (by enabling/disabling interface,...), but it always assigned the same address, 169.254.0.33. Not sure whether this is another non-compliance, though)

Comment: Windows uses a hash of the MAC address to pick the IPv4 Link-Local address and has for a long time so not surprising the interface keeps getting the same address.

Comment: Just curious - what does it matter?

Comment: @RyanRies I don't know which part of the question you refer to, so I'll address both. Regarding the IPv4 range - just that our software implements different policies depending on whether the PC is on a link-local address or not. So far, we were checking the range as per the RFC, but , as it is often the case, reality doesn't always follow RFCs.          And regarding the fact that the address was constant, we were just curious. Again, following the RFC, it should be produced by a pseudo-random number generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice Microsoft uses the full /16.

"By default, the alternate IPv4 address is in the range from 169.254.0.1 to 169.254.255.254 with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0."

Configuring TCP/IP networking
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163570.aspx